# ExtJS comboBox only sets value from JSON if no [] in name

Tags: json, extjs, extjs3

using ExtJS 3 here. I just noticed (in reply to my previous question) that the problem appears only when I'm not sending more than one combobox name. I currently have setup my combobox's name like this `name[]` because I will send an array of values. If I remove the array `[]`, it works but I can only grab the last sent combobox value. My config is a SuperBoxSelect for multiple select purposes but this happens to my combobox also:

```
new Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect({
       store:storeForCompanies,
       fieldLabel:'CN',
       id:'companyField',
       displayField: 'company_name',
       valueField: 'id',
       name:'cn',
       hiddenName: 'company[]',
        typeAhead: true,
        mode: 'remote',
        minChars : 0,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText:'- Choose -',
        selectOnFocus:true,
        allowBlank:true,
       width: 350
})
```

Do I have any other options to send those ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your combobox config

Comment: Changed the facts a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I have also tried to load the combobox store prior to form load and still no value set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not found an "out of the box" solution so I attached a success handler to the form.load() that sets value of the combobox to the returned JSON result, like this:

```
success: function(form, action)
{
Ext.getCmp('companyField').setValue(action.result.data.company);
}
```

This way it works, don't know why I have to manually set the value for that combobox, I'm just glad I "fixed" a 2 day problem in my application and I am opened for any other suggestion that can point me in getting it fixed in a proper way.

Thanks.